Moodle local installation in local with wamp server
I copy a moodle code folder alraedy costomised from a mac and want to run it on my windows with wamp server.  I've already modify the config.php file
But when I try to access the web app trough the wamp navigator I got à php Fatal error:

Uncaught error : Cache class not found in ~localdirectory/www/mdl/moodle/lib/classes/string_manager_standard.php on line   82

I try looping for cache option in the navigatrice trough the console and comparate the initial classes files to the one I copy but I can't find nothing

Are they both running the same versions of PHP?

No there were not running the same version of PHP i realise it later. Thanks for confirming my doubts
